# Does Froyo fix Samsung Galaxy S I9000's GPS problem?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, gps, 2.2-froyo

There have been reports that Samsung Galaxy S has problems with its GPS that render the GPS almost unusable.  Does the Android 2.2 update fix that?

Comment: The 2.1.1 update changed my unusable GPS to acceptable GPS. I don't always get a fix but once I do it works pretty OK.

Comment: See also: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6981/how-can-i-fix-the-gps-on-my-samsung-galaxy-s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I didn't find anything wrong with the GPS on mine (AT&T Captivate). You didn't say which version of the Galaxy you have (Captivate, Fascinate, etc.), but I know that before Froyo even, AT&T did push a separate update to their customers which supposedly was to fix the GPS (I don't know if it did though, since as I said I wasn't having issues before the update).

Answer (score 2):

Guides to fix the GPS issues with Captivate and Vibrant have just been posted.

http://androidcommunity.com/samsung-posts-gps-fix-guide-for-captivate-and-vibrant-20101130/

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** [Check out my guide on how to improve Galaxy S GPS performance](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/6981/1465).

With GPS on the Galaxy S, the answer is always "maybe".  New code works for some people, changing settings works for some people, and sometimes nothing works.

Answer (score 1):

The latest update on the Samsung Vibrant (JI6) fixed GPS issues for 2.1. A similar update has been pushed to all the variants, as far as I know. As you can tell from the other responses, GPS issues aren't universal and even for those having trouble it wasn't always completely broken. It is safe to say it is fixed now, though -- and I see no reason to think it would be broken again in 2.2.

Comment: It's definitely not safe to say it's fixed.  I've heard more people say that JI2 / JI6 fixed GPS than broke it, but for the majority of us there's been no change.

Answer (score 0):

I can't confirm any GPS problems with my Galaxy S I9000 so far with 2.1. Unfortunately Froyo is not yet available for that device.

Comment: As an update, the official Froyo release started rolling out to unbranded Galaxy S devices in the UK on the 4th of November. Carrier branded devices (and the rest of the world) are expected to be released over the next few weeks.

Comment: Yes, now i am on froyo (in germany the rollout startet one day later). And i also had no gps issues on 2.2 so far.

Answer (score 0):

Captivate received a software update a month or so ago(I think it was later September or early October 2010) that fixed most GPS problems.

I still have some errors, but the major problem I had was that cellular assisted was not enabled. This is a must for the samsung captivate.

Answer (score 0):

Well I also have problems GPS lock issue on my Galaxy 5 i5500, hope this can fix your phone. I got tips to fix this issue.
Remember to write down the default setting before change the GPS setting below, in case you want to go back.

Make sure GPS has been activated.

1. Press `*#*#1472365#*#*`. This will
   bring to GPS setting.
2. Settings -> Parameter Settings ->
   Address -> Server Type: 1x MPC
3. Settings -> Parameter Settings ->
   Position mode: option3
4. Settings -> Fix Request Settings ->
   Session Operation: Standalone
5. Settings -> Fix Request Settings ->
   Server Option: Local
6. gpsOne XTRA -> Xtra Enable: Enable

Answer (score 0):

No,
After updating my Samsung Galaxy S from JP8 2.1 version, that was working normally with GPS, but losing GPS capture some times...

Now with Froyo 2.2, the capture GPS works very well, but the position is completely erratic and is going 100 meters from the site where I am....

I don't know what to do, and I didn't find any solution on internet ... and if you are waiting for Samsung help you could die waiting first.

Answer (score 0):

No, I upgraded to the unofficial FROYO (Android 2.2) for Samsung Captivate and the GPS sucks. The signal does not lock and when it does, after waiting for days and sucking up the battery, it loses the signal just as fast. I am so frustrated with the GPS problem that I am thinking about switching carriers to get a different brand phone - like HTC or Motorola.

Answer (score 0):

I also upgraded my Samsung Galaxy S to Froyo 2.2 and lost my GPS lock that I had on 2.1 which sometimes worked. I tried to a factory reset and cleaned everything on my phone and after the reset comepleted I had to input information and the first thing I tried was GPS and still could not get a lock. I download GPS locator before and that also did not lock onto a GPS. I will try what "user1100" said and see if that helps.

Bottom line Froyo 2.2 has GPS lock issues.. maps and navigation works without a GPS lock..:(

Answer (score 0):

I am writing to inform you that this link is very helpful to fix GPS problems coming with samsung galaxy s froyo. But please be aware that this may have a risk (less probably) but worked very fine with me.

http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/how-to-fix-gps-on-samsung-galaxy-s-eclair-and-froyo/

step 7 does not appear in the settings so I passed that option. it is working now.

SAMSUNG GALAXY S 2.2 FROYO edition.

Answer (score 0):

There was definitely a problem with the GPS on my Samsung Captivate I purchased from AT&T a week after it launched, but I wouldn't classify it as unusable.  It would take several minutes sometimes to first fix even when outdoors, but it would stay fixed as long as nothing obstructed it, such as my car ceiling.  If it had a fix recently, it would be quicker at getting a fix as well.  I used GPS Status to keep the GPS Almanac up to date which helped a bit, and applied several fixes people had suggested with minor improvements.  Even official updates from Samsung had little improvement.  I finally decided to replace my ROM with a third party and my GPS was greatly improved unlike anything Samsung had provided before.  Generally, any third-party ROM using the JK4 modem like [Paragon](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=915698)