# Does assisted GPS fix Samsung Galaxy S's GPS problems?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, samsung-galaxy-s, gps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does Froyo fix Samsung Galaxy S I9000's GPS problem?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2462/does-froyo-fix-samsung-galaxy-s-i9000s-gps-problem)

the GPS on Samsung Galaxy S is said to be somewhat broken.  Is this true even when using [assisted GPS](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1522/what-is-assisted-gps)?

Comment: This is going to be a difficult question for people to answer for you. There are a lot of Galaxy S users (including me) who've never had any GPS problems. There are some who seem to have more problems on some software versions than others. You really need to try it out on your phone and see.

Comment: More or less the same as: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2462/does-froyo-fix-samsung-galaxy-s-i9000s-gps-problem

Comment: See also: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6981/how-can-i-fix-the-gps-on-my-samsung-galaxy-s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I don't have any problems with GPS on my Galaxy, but I do get a lock a few seconds quicker if I have the aGPS functions switched on. It also means that I get a "rough" lock while I'm waiting (this rough lock is the one with the big blue circle, which is about half a mile wide when I'm in my home town, or about 30m wide in London.

(On Froyo at least) the settings to turn this on and off are in **Settings**, **Location and Security**, then you can use both "**Use wireless networks** *Location determined by Wi-Fi and/or mobile networks*" and "**Use sensor aiding** *Enhance positioning and save power using sensors*" to switch the aGPS on or off

Answer (score 1):

Guides to fix the GPS issues with Captivate and Vibrant have just been posted.

http://androidcommunity.com/samsung-posts-gps-fix-guide-for-captivate-and-vibrant-20101130/

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a Galaxy S with a broken GPS? what do you mean by broken? My Galaxy S (2.1) GPS took forever to find my location without "Use wireless networks" as described by GAThrawn, but once I enable it I almost have no problems finding my location quickly

Comment: I am in the market for one, and I want to make sure that if the GPS doesn't work, I have some way to fix it.

Comment: maybe "broken GPS" that they say is similar to what I used to have. but when I activate assisted GPS the problem goes away.