# How can I geo-tag a photo after I've taken it?

Tags: geolocation, photos

Is there an app for that? :)

(For when [automatic tagging](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3333/how-can-i-make-my-photos-automatically-geo-tagged) fails)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually I found such an app, after a fair bit of searching.

[Photo Geolocator](http://www.appbrain.com/app/photogeolocator/edu.uoc.mperezma.main) ([Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/photogeolocator/))

Currently you can't look up locations via an address, so it only really works for nearby locations, but that's still better than having to edit images on a PC, IMO.

[image: qr tag]

Answer (score 1):

If you know where the photo was taken then a desktop app that lets you edit the picture's  EXIF info, like [Microsoft's Pro Photo Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=184075D2-40B5-4172-88AE-878F81896D4D&displaylang=en), will let you add a Geotag later. In Pro Photo Tools it's as easy as using the built-in Bing map viewer to put a pin on the map, no need to mess around with latitudes and longitudes if you don't want to.

As for editing on the phone, I can se a lot of apps that let you view or erase the EXIF info, including plotting your pictures on maps, but can't see one that lets you add this info on the phone.

You could use something like [GeoLogger](http://www.androlib.com/android.application.it-gelain-geologger-xAtF.aspx) to log your position on the phone, so that you can use that later on to add to photos if they haven't been properly geotagged.

Answer (score 0):

On Android you can use the free [a Photo Manager/a Photo Map/androFotoFinder](https://github.com/k3b/androFotoFinder)  app:

- Select one or more photos in gallery view that should receive the same geo-info
- From Menu use "set geo"
- pick a geo from a map
- press ok

For details see [Howto-geotag-multible-photos](https://github.com/k3b/APhotoManager/wiki/Howto-geotag-multible-photos).

The app is available via [f-droid.org installer](https://f-droid.org/) or as [apk internet download](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=de.k3b.android.androFotoFinder) but not on google play store.

Note I am the author of the app and i manually geotagged more that 10 000 jpgs with the app