# Does Samsung Galaxy S keep GPS location in camera taken photo metadata?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, gps, camera, geolocation, geotagging

Does anyone know if Samsung Galaxy S GT-I9000's camera taken photos keep information about GPS location from when they were taken?

Thank you

Comment: See this previous question for tips if the geo-tagging isn't working for you at the moment http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3333/how-can-i-make-my-photos-automatically-geo-tagged

Comment: The easiest way to tell if the picture has been geotagged is to open the picture in the gallery press Menu, More, Show on map.

Comment: Any other ideas? I want to dissable geotagging. I don´t want to give up my location. It´s could be very dangerous.

Comment: Hi. You're not really giving away your location per se. If you send someone files they will be able to see coordinates of where they were taken, however you can "Clear personal data" from the JPEG files in Windows 7 (surely other OS too). Also, if your GPS is turned off, your location will not be determined.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It can if you turn the function on in the settings.  In the settings menu there's an option for "GPS", that when checked turns on [geotagging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geotagging):

[image]

*via [GSM Arena](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_i9000_galaxy_s-review-478p6.php) & [CareAce](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_i9000_galaxy_s-review-478p6.php)*

Comment: If GPS is closed and wireless networks as well, will it force open them to get location? Or for geotagging to work they must be user-enabled before taking pictures?

Comment: Also, I seem to be missing that GPS checkbox from the settings interface... After Review i see Shutter Sound which should be on the next page according to the screenshot above. Any clues?

Comment: Just searched for it (StackExchange makes you lazy) and it turns out Froyo made GeoTracking default and unchangeable in Galaxy S. Haha...

Answer (score 1):

There is no setting in the camera phone for GPS on my Galaxy S GT19000.

I disabled everything in `Settings > location and security`. It was still geotagging my photos, and I couldn't work out how it was doing that. But if you go to `applications > local`, it was here for me. Just visit the `Settings` section.

Nasty.

Answer (score -1):

I just did a reset of all camera settings and the geotagging disappeared. Since this is what I wanted, I'm happy. When I bought it it was off (I think) and it got turned on sometime last month.