# How do you disable geotagging for stock camera?

Tags: gps, camera, 4.3-jelly-bean, geotagging

I have stock (i.e. pure Google with no manufacturer customizations) Android 4.3 and I use the built-in camera app. I searched around on the camera app settings but couldn't find any mention of GPS or geotagging. I also searched around the settings → location but didn't find anything specific to the camera.

How do you disable geotagging for the built-in camera app?

Comment: People can help you, if you mention your device name or model with android version. Because different device has different type of settings, even if they are Android.

Comment: re - "what device is this": I listed it as "stock android 4.3" because I believe all stock android 4.3 devices should have the same built-in camera app. I was trying to make the question more universal instead of limiting it to one hardware device.

Comment: I don't want to undermine your beliefs, but different manufacturers tend to exchange such components, so for this I have to agree with chris. I however agree with you that you mentioned the Android version already :)

Comment: To the best of my knowledge 'stock Android 4.3' built-in camera app will be the same no matter what hardware as long as the hardware is running stock Android 4.3 (EX: Nexus 4, 'Pure Version' of HTC One, 'Pure Version' of Galaxy S4). When I say 'stock Android 4.3' I am referring to the version of Android that does not have manufacturer added skins like HTC Sense, Samsung Touchwize, etc. I'm no expert though. Just a casual user.

Comment: @TrevorBoydSmith Thanks for clarifying. Usually when people say "stock", they mean whatever came with the phone, even if that includes manufacturer customizations. That's why everyone wants to be sure. I've taken the liberty of adding that information to your question.

Comment: @DanHulme Thanks for informing me on the usage of 'stock' in this context (Funny how the meaning of words always changes depending on the situation, group!). Also thanks for updating the question for me.

Comment: A tip, if you're about to upload a picture (even if it has geotagging in there or not), upload to imgur server where it actually does strip out the EXIF data (that is where geotagging info gets stored in) or look at this [answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/11890/can-i-disable-geotagging-and-delete-prior-geotag-information-in-photos/12111#12111) to manually strip out the EXIF data yourself. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Follow these steps, if the icon in (3) has a line through it then it will not store your location in your images.

[image: 4.3 camera]

1. Open the menu
2. Choose settings
3. Tap the location icon